# JMS - How to send message back to the client?

Tags: jms, objectoutputstream

This is my client side code :

public class ABCServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                 HttpServletResponse response){
//do blah blah
String msg = null;

java.io.OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
java.io.ObjectOutputStream oos = new java.io.ObjectOutputStream(os);
oos.writeObject(msg);
msg = null;
oos.flush();
oos.close();
}
```

I don't know how using the above code my listener gets kicked off -

```
public class ABCListener implements MessageListener {

@Override
public void onMessage(Message arg0) {
 AbstractJDBCFacade façade = null;
 try{
    façade = something;
    throw new UserException();
 }catch(UserException ex){
    log.error("ABC Exception " + ex);
 }
```

Configuration :

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">....

<bean id="jmsQueue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">

<bean id="listenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer102">
```

I have 3 questions : 
1. without putting it on the queue explicitly , how a listener gets invoked? 
2. When onMessage method throws UserException, instead of logging I want to pass the message to the client. How can I do that ? 
3. Why would someone use JndiObjectFactoryBean instead of ActiveMQ...

Answer (score 6):

JMS by design was supposed to be asynchronous and one-way. Even "synchronous" jms with using receive method of consumer will internally turn into creating a new temporary queue. And here we come to the second point about it's one-way nature. JMS queue was supposed to be one-way and that's why it is called point-to-point (http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/PointToPointChannel.html). Of course technically with some dancing you will manage to achieve what you want but it is bad practice which will also lead to performance degradation due to the fact that you will need filtering.

To get this thing work fast the best way will be to have exactly one logical receiver (of course you can use concurrent cosumers for one receiver but that should be one logical consumer without any need of filtering the message).

> 1. without putting it on the queue explicitly , how a listener gets invoked?

Listener get invoked only when a message comes to a queue. Thats the only way to get it work as it was supposed to work.

In general there are two types of message consuming models: push (also known as event-driven consuming) and poll. In case of using push model all listeners (according to canonical observer pattern) got registered somewhere in the broker and then, when broker receive new message in some queue, it executes listener's method. On the others side in polling model consumer take care itself about receiving messages. So with some interval it comes to a broker and checks the queue for new messages.

Push model: http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/EventDrivenConsumer.html

Poll model: http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/PollingConsumer.html

> 2. When onMessage method throws UserException, instead of logging I want to pass the message to the client. How can I do that ?

Thats a very bad practice. Of course technically you can achieve it with dirty tricks but thats not the right way of using jms. When onMessage throws the exception then message wont be taken from the queue (of course if u did not reconfigured acknowledge mods or used another tricks). So the best way of solving your probem fmpv is to use redelivery limit on message and a dead letter queue(http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/DeadLetterChannel.html). If system was not able to process the message after some attempts (redelivery limit shows exactly this) then broker remove message from the queue and send it to a so-called dead letter queue where all failed (from the point of broker) messages are stored. And then client can read that queue and decide what to do with message.

In amq: http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html

If you want to use so-called "synchronous" features in JMS and really there is no way of using dead letter queue or smth like that then actually you can use consumer.recieve method on the client. But in this case you should send response on every message. In case of success you can send one message and in case of failure error messages. And so a client will be able to understand what is going on. But i dont think that you need such a huge overhead cause actually you need only failure messages. Also in this case you will have to take care about appropriate receive timeouts.

> 3. Why would someone use JndiObjectFactoryBean instead of ActiveMQ...

That's cause you are using Spring and there are additional features especially for spring.

PS: 
1. For consuming:

> How can I send a message using just this piece of code? Don't I need
>   to put this on a queue? java.io.OutputStream os =
>   response.getOutputStream(); java.io.ObjectOutputStream oos = new
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream(os); oos.writeObject(msg);
>   For receiving smth like this:
>         `

```
    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.
      jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="baseJNDITemplate"/>
        <property name="jndiName"  

        value="weblogic.jms.ConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="queue"  class="org.springframework.
     jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="baseJNDITemplate"/>
        <property name="jndiName" value="#{properties.queueName}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageListenerContainer"              
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.
      DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="destination" ref="queue"/>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener"/>
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageListener" class="com.example.ABCListener"/>
```

And then simply all logic for message processing will be in the listener.

For sending smth like this in config:

```
<bean id="jmsQueueTemplate" 
  class="org.springframework.
     jms.core.JmsTemplate">
<property name="connectionFactory">
    <ref bean="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
</property>
<property name="destinationResolver">
    <ref bean="jmsDestResolver"/>
</property>

...
</bean>

<bean id="jmsDestResolver"
      class=" org.springframework.jms.support.destination.
      JndiDestinationResolver"/>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jms/myCF"/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="amq con fact here"/>
</bean>
```

and in code simply use jmsTemplate.send(queue, messageCreator) method:

```
@Autowired
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Test(enabled = false)
public void testJmsSend(final String msg) throws Exception {
    JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
    template.send("test_queue", new MessageCreator() {
        @Override
        public Message createMessage(Session session) 
          throws JMSException {
            return session.createTextMessage(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cspr_data_access_jms.html

> 2. I believe Dead channel comes in picture only when the message is not properly received by the receiver. In my case, the receiver
>      received it and processed it, however while processing it failed with
>      some exception. I want to let the sender know that there was a
>      exception and the message did not process successfully. I can do this
>      using a response queue but I don't want to do that, can the receiver
>      receive a message from the sender on the same queue ? How?

Dead letter channel is a kind of error handling for message processing also. If message processing had failed then after the limit end it got transferred there. It is not actually only for transport issues but also for processing issues. If the message processing got failed with exception then message will stay in the queue and wont be acked by default. So what we should do with this message? For example if it failed due to our database error or smth like this? We should initiate error-handling process, notify assurance systems and stakeholders, collect all necessary info and preserve the message. Due to this kind of queues, which was create d exactly for that, it is much easier. And then customer support team will investigate error queue for further analysis of what has happened. Also we have monitoring tools for notifications and statistics collection on such errors. After understanding what has happened message got removed from the queue and archived.

> After processing a message, the consumer is responsible for deleting
>   the message. If the consumer doesn't delete the message, for example
>   because because it crashed while processing the message, the message
>   becomes visible again after the message's Visibility Timeout expires.
>   Each time this happens, the message's receive count is increased.
>   When this count reaches a configured limit, the message is placed in a
>   designated Dead Letter Queue.

http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/DeadLetterChannel.html

> I can do this using a response queue but I don't want to do that, can
>   the receiver receive a message from the sender on the same queue ?
>   How?

For you it will look like it's the same queue but internally new temporary queue will be created. To achieve that you should use jms request\reply message pattern. More here: http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html

> The only part still confuses me is : If I expect my JMS listener
>   (receiver) to listen to the queue, then my sender should also
>   implement JMS and connect to the same queue and send a message. But in
>   the ABCListener application that I am supporting does not have any
>   configuration where the sender is configured to the queue. All the
>   sender does is 3 lines of code : java.io.OutputStream os =
>   response.getOutputStream(); java.io.ObjectOutputStream oos = new
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream(os); oos.writeObject(msg); Literally, that
>   is it. I don't know how it still works!

Of course 3 lines of code with outputstream do nothing except populating msg string. To send any jms message to the queue you anyway will have to use JMS Api or some library like Spring which wrap it by adding additional features.

I've wrote simple samples to get it more clear.

1. Modified servlet for asynchronous processing with dead letter queue (for dlq you should create also another listener ofc)

   ```
   public class AsynchronousJmsSenderServlet extends HttpServlet {
   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       String msg = null;

       try (java.io.OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream()) {
           try(java.io.ObjectOutputStream oos = new java.io.ObjectOutputStream(os)) {
               oos.writeObject(msg);
           }
       }

       sendJmsMessage(msg);
   }

   private void sendJmsMessage(final String msg) {
       ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null; //here get it in some way from spring
       JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
       template.send("your_queue_name", new MessageCreator() {
           @Override
           public Message createMessage(Session session)
                   throws JMSException {
               return session.createTextMessage(msg);
           }
       });
   }
   }
   ```
2. And here is the code for "synchronous" processing and status reply messages

   ```
   public class SynchronousJmsSenderServlet extends HttpServlet {

   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       String msg = null;
       try (java.io.OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream()) {
           try(java.io.ObjectOutputStream oos = new java.io.ObjectOutputStream(os)) {
               oos.writeObject(msg);
           }
       }
       sendJmsMessage(msg);
   }

   private void sendJmsMessage(final String msg) {
       ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null; //here get it in some way from spring
       JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);

       Message reply = template.sendAndReceive("your_queue_name", new MessageCreator() {
           @Override
           public Message createMessage(Session session)
                   throws JMSException {
               return session.createTextMessage(msg);
           }
       });

       if(reply instanceof TextMessage) {
           try {
               String status = ((TextMessage) reply).getText();
               //do error handling if status is error
           } catch (JMSException ex) {
               throw new RuntimeException("Unable to get status message", ex);
           }
       } else {
           throw new RuntimeException("Only text messages are supported");
       }
   }
   }


   public class SynchronousJmsMessageListener implements SessionAwareMessageListener {

   @Override
   public void onMessage(Message request, Session session) throws JMSException {
       try {
           //do some processing
           sendReply(request, session, "OK");
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           sendReply(request, session, "Error: " + ex.toString());
       }
   }

   private void sendReply(Message request, Session session, String status) {
       try {
           TextMessage reply = null; //for example you can use ActiveMQTextMessage here
           reply.setJMSCorrelationID(request.getJMSCorrelationID());
           reply.setText(status);

           MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(reply.getJMSReplyTo());
           producer.send(reply);
       } catch (JMSException exception) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Unable to send reply", exception);
       }
   }
   }
   ```

You will need Spring 5 to have sendAndReceive method on jmsTemplate. Or you will have to do all that manually.

PS1: Please let me know if that will work

Comment: 1. How can I send a message using just this piece of code? Don't I need to put this on a queue?      java.io.OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
java.io.ObjectOutputStream oos = new java.io.ObjectOutputStream(os);
oos.writeObject(msg);

Comment: 2. I believe Dead channel comes in picture only when the message is not properly received by the receiver. In my case, the receiver received it and processed it, however while processing it failed with some exception. I want to let the sender know that there was a exception and the message did not process successfully. I can do this using a response queue but I don't want to do that, can the receiver receive a message from the sender on the same queue ? How?

Comment: Answered inline)

Comment: Thanks for all this information. The only part still confuses me is : If I expect my JMS listener (receiver) to listen to the queue, then my sender should also implement JMS and connect to the same queue and send a message. But in the ABCListener application that I am supporting does not have any configuration where the sender is configured to the queue. All the sender does is 3 lines of code : java.io.OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
java.io.ObjectOutputStream oos = new java.io.ObjectOutputStream(os);
oos.writeObject(msg); Literally, that is it. I don't know how it still works!

Comment: To be able to send smth through JMS anyway you will have to use JMS Api or some libs which wrap it and a broker specific code which implement that API. For amq in case of messages this can be https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/command/ActiveMQTextMessage.html which implements Message. Ive add inline some code samples to get it more clear. Hope it will help)